# VS application can't connect to database after attaching it in SSMS

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I have a windows form application (developed in VS Express 2013) that connects through an instance of SQL Server 2012 to a database.  Both the application and database are on my local system; I just needed a GUI to more easily interface with this very large database that stores my research data.  When I initially compile and deploy the application, it works fine and has no connection problems with the database.  However, if I then attach the database in SQL Server Management Studio (which I sometimes want to do) I get an error the next time I try to use the application - "Cannot open database ..... requested by the login, the login failed".  I get this error even if I take the database offline and detach it before quitting SSMS.  And just to be clear - I'm not making any changes to the database in SSMS, I'm just looking at the data.  The connection string used by VS is Data Source (LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\CollectionMetricsDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True.

Any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the instance of SQL Server 2012 has a max number of concurrent connections and you exceed that with your two connections at once (SSMS connection and application's connection).  Check the settings in SSMS.

Another thing to try - Based on your connection string, you are using Integrated Security, which in my experience means the application connects using Windows credentials.  That can be fragile, because it means that whatever 'user' runs the application (if hosted in IIS, this will be the App Pool user) is the one whose Windows credentials are used.  I would suggest creating a SQL login user (in SSMS) for the database, with db_owner access, and then changing the application's connection to be username/password based instead.  You may need to enable Mixed Authentication for the SQL Server instance in SSMS if it doesn't already allow it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect in SSMS with the localDB connection string. Attaching it will prevent it from working with localDB.

In SSMS, create a connection to `(LocalDB)\v11.0`. You should see your DB there already.

Comment: He can connect in ssms

Comment: @Mike: He is attaching it to the server, which lock the DB, using localDB does not lock it from other localDB connections using it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are connecting to the database file directly not through SQL Server.

Only one user can have a lock on the file at the time.

You need to recreate a connection string for your app.

That is why you were needing to detach the database.

Since this is only a personal project you could live with things as they are, at least you know the server is only running when you need it.

[create connection msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4yys16a(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: @jamieivy, Can you tell us which solution worked to allow your connection to the database, so you can help future users with a similar problem?